# how to convert the "8:00AM" into seconds only?

Tags: jquery

Here I'm converting only time into seconds using jQuery I don't understand how will I do it without using date.Is that possible to convert only time in string like `array=["8:00AM", "1:00PM", "12:00PM", "12:00AM"]` into seconds using jQuery ***without using date***. can anybody help me.Thnak you in advance.

Comment: What **exactly** do you mean by _"convert to seconds"_? Seconds since when? Midnight? Please give some examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@vikas kumar, try with solution

```
<script>
function parsehhmmsst(arg) {
    var result = 0, arr = arg.split(':')
    if (arr[0] < 12) {
        result = arr[0] * 3600 // hours
    }
    var min = (arr[1]).replace("AM","").replace("PM","");
    result += min * 60 // minutes
    if (arg.indexOf('P') > -1) {  // 8:00 PM > 8:00 AM
        result += 43200
    }
    return result
}
alert(parsehhmmsst("8:00AM"));
</script>
```

Comment: it is possible for array if i have `time=["8:00AM", "10:00AM", "8:00AM", "10:00AM" ,"1:00PM", "2:00PM"]`??

Comment: here you need sum of all time or the list of seconds in array?

Comment: Actually I have an array of time like above i told you in comment. will this  code works?

Comment: yes definitely, you need to split each array object convert them and push the converted value in new array